# How to find the probability that Xavier wears a matching shirt and tie on Thursday

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The question is as follows
"When Xavier started work, he bought five shirts with matching ties, but he has since thrown the ties into
the same drawer and hung the shirts at random in his wardrobe. Each day he picks a shirt and a tie at
random to wear and then throws them in the used pile at the end of the day. Find the probability that:
He wears a matching shirt and tie on Thursday"
I do not understand how to even attempt such a question. Please help.

Comment: Hint: what have you tried?

Comment: i have tried drawing a tree diagram yet it got very complicated very quickly, with too many things to consider

Comment: Then try with a simpler problem first, with only two or three ties/shirts/days.

Comment: Note that the answer depends on the fact that Thursday is the fourth day of a working week. The answer would be differentif it was another day. Now take into account the fact that the only thing that matters is what shirts/ties were picked during the first 3 days, and **it doesn't matter in which particular order**.

Comment: Also it doesn't matter what exact colours were picked, but only what pattern of colours (matching/non matching) remains to be picked.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier The probability would be the same for Monday, or Tuesday, or Wednesday, or Friday, though.

Comment: @ClementC. could you care to explain please

Comment: This is sampling without replacement , since the ties and shirts are thrown in the used pile and not available the next day. You have five matching outfits $(t_1,s_1),\cdots,(t_5,s_5)$. Each day, Xavier picks independently two numbers $i,j$ among the numbers still available (among the numbers remaining for the ties and the shirts, respectively). You want to know the probability that, on the fourth day, you end up with $i=j$.

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to having two permutations ${i_1},{i_2},{i_3},{i_4},{i_5}$ (choice of tie) and ${j_1},{j_2},{j_3},{j_4},{j_5}$ chosen uniformly at random (and independently), and asking the probability that $i_4=j_4$.

Can you argue that this probability is $1/5$?

Comment: @ClementC. the advice I gave is applicable in a broader context *and* has the advantage of having a PSQ OP actually doing some work instead of collecting answer from Mr Sandman.

Comment: @ClementC. unfortunately no, could you show me how it is 1/5?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier My comment was in reaction to the fact that you wrote *"The answer would be different if it was another day."*
It may be applicable "in a broader context", but it's misleading (false).

Comment: @ClementC. Wrong. The answer is not the result, the answer is the process to get it [as a teacher, I will put zero marks to a correct answer with no explanations]. And if you're not used to doing such calculations, then you should do them once instead of being happy with smarty tricks.

Comment: Oh, my. @ArnaudMortier, no need to be aggressive. You said something wrong, then are attacking me (you may note I didn't give the full answer).

Comment: can someone just tell me how to do this question please?

Comment: @ClementC. You're interpreting my comments as aggressive for some reason, yet I'm totally calm here. And I also didn't say something wrong, *you* interpreted it as such, as *you* figured I was talking about the final answer, which I obviously wasn't. And if only the final answer matters to you, then you also gave that in full.

Comment: @Jin We've given you at least two ways to do the question.

Comment: ? You literally wrote "Note that the answer depends on the fact that Thursday is the fourth day of a working week. **The answer would be different if it was another day.**" [Emphasis mine] If your goal is to help the OP, then that is misleading, since the answer would be the same if I replaced Thursday by, e,g, Monday.

Comment: could you please write out a method

Comment: i am in high school so please give a simple explanation, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let $(T_1,S_1),\dots, (T_5,S_5)$ be the 5 (different) matching pairs of ties and shirts. Each day, a tie $T_i$ and a shirt $S_j$ are chosen uniformly at random among the remaining ties and shirts (the first day, $i$ is chosen uniformly in $\{1,\dots,5\}$, and so is $j$; the second day, $i$ is chosen among the four remaining numbers for the ties, etc.).

This may be hard to get a grip on, so one can think of it the following way: 2 independent permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, denoted $(i_1,\dots,i_5)$ and $(j_1,\dots,j_5)$ are chosen independently and uniformly at random. On day $k$, the tie $T_{i_k}$ and the shirt $S_{j_k}$ are worn.

The question is:

> What is the probability that $i_4=j_4$? (i.e., that on day 4 the tie and shirt match)

A brute force way is as follows to answer this question is as follows.

$$
\mathbb{P}\{i_4=j_4\} = \sum_{n=1}^5 \mathbb{P}\{i_4=j_4=n\}
= \sum_{n=1}^5 \mathbb{P}\{i_4=n\}\mathbb{P}\{j_4=n\} = \sum_{n=1}^5 \frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{5}
$$
where the second equality is by independence, and the third by the fact that, for any fixed $n$, a fifth of all permutations of $\{1,\dots,5\}$ satisfy $i_4=n$.

Comment: Note: this is a CW (Community Wiki) answer, feel free to edit as you please. It belongs to nobody.